# ffmpeg on windows getting error

Tags: ffmpeg

Im running ffmpeg on xampp through command line
I keep on getting this error

```
ffmpeg version N-55644-g68b63a3 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers built on Aug 19 2013 20:27:12 with gcc 4.7.3 (GCC) configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig
```

This project was built many years ago and i just copied it to a new server

Comment: I don't see any errors, and you didn't show your command so it is not possible to tell you what is wrong. But your ffmpeg is ancient. [Download a new ffmpeg](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/) and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm running `ffmpeg` on XAMPP through the command line and I keep getting this error [...]

As noted already, this isn't an error. This is a standard `ffmpeg` banner describing the build of `ffmpeg` you're using (including related build flags), which `ffmpeg` displays by default when invoked from the command line.

You can suppress the majority of this banner by running `ffmpeg` with the `-hide_banner` option ex.:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner [...]
```

Where `[...]` above represents any other commands you want to run with `ffmpeg` (e.g. to alter a file).

To be clear, if `ffmpeg` isn't doing what you wish it to, this is (at best) only tangentially related to that issue.